# Alert window using php

Tags: php

I am newbie to php and i am trying to create a alert window/popup box to display to all the users who are logged into the application using a button pressed by administrator,but don't know how to do that.My application is different IP address.Any help would be appreciated.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "System update is in progress";
}
?>
```

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit"> should be <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript for your popup and inside your javascript code you can use php to retrieve data from the server and then assign it to a javascript variable.